# What is the purpose of a manifest.json file in an Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, service-worker, angular-service-worker

First of all I didn't know anything about the potential existence of such file in the context of an Angular 5+ Project. I have a running Angular 5 project which doesn't have this manifest.json file in it. I decided to add [service worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) facility to improve the performance of the application. The service worker didn't get activated and I did a little research on the problem and came across the following [open github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8779) in which some people mentioned they fixed the issue using a manifest.json. What is this file? Why couldn't it be part of the Angular CLI config? On what condition would you require one? Where is the potential documentation?

Comment: A manifest generally define rules and configuration for an application

Comment: This is  not the answer to the question. I am not sure whether you have ever done any Angular project but there are many configuration files already in place and application already operates without the need for an extra one.

Comment: No it's not an answer but a comment that may add to your reflexion maybe

Answer (score 7):

The Manifest file is used for the project name, icons, metadata etc to Home screen.

```
{
"name": "Project Example",
"short_name": "project",
"icons": [{
"src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
"sizes": "128x128",
"type": "image/png"
}, {
"src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
"sizes": "144x144",
"type": "image/png"
}, {
"src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
"sizes": "152x152",
"type": "image/png"
}, {
"src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
"sizes": "192x192",
"type": "image/png"
}, {
"src": "images/icons/icon-256x256.png",
"sizes": "256x256",
"type": "image/png"
}],
"start_url": "/index.html",
"display": "standalone",
"background_color": "#3E4EB8",
"theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the MDN documentation :

> The web app manifest provides information about an application (such
>   as name, author, icon, and description) in a JSON text file. The
>   purpose of the manifest is to install web applications to the
>   homescreen of a device, providing users with quicker access and a
>   richer experience.

It seems to be a critical part of creating a PWA (Progressive Web Application)

In this manifest you will be able to define for example Service Workers :

> A service worker is a script that your browser runs in the background,
>   separate from a web page, opening the door to features that don’t need
>   a web page or user interaction.

To create a PWA you need those two aspects

Answer (score -1):

You may need dynamic inputs, elements, icons, data, components in your projects.
Thats the reason we need manifest json.